# Criação de card em CSS

Tags: css, react, layout-responsivo

Boas, estou tentando transformar uma tabela em cards quando o site for aberto em um dispositivo mobile, porém não entendo muito de CSS. Estou me baseando nesse [modelo](https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MyqmdM), no meu viraram card apenas os dados, porém o cabeçario sumiu, alguém poderia me explicar o que aconteceu? (Estou usando JSX)

Minha Tabela:

```
   <Table className="customers center table-cfg">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Nome da Empresa</th>
            <th>CNPJ</th>
            <th>QTD de Beneficiários</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.companies.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={item.login}>
              <td>{item.login}</td>
              <td>{item.name_company}</td>
              <td>{item.cnpj}</td>
              <td>{item.amount_beneficiary}</td>
            </tr>
          ))
          }
        </tbody>
      </Table>
```

Meu CSS:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .content{width: 100%}

    /* .table-cfg thead{display: none}
    .table-cfg {display: none} */

    th{display: flex; flex-direction: column}

    table {
      border: 0;
    }

    table caption {
      font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    table thead {
      border: none;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
    }

    table tr {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: .625em;
    }

    table td {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      display: block;
      font-size: .8em;
      text-align: right;
    }

    table td::before {
      /*
      * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
      content: attr(aria-label);
      */
      content: attr(data-label);
      float: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    table td:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
```

Meu resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa Leandro tudo certo meu camarada?

veja que no exemplo que você mandou em cada **td** existe um atributo **data-label** segue o exemplo:

```
<tr>
   <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
   <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
   <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
   <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
</tr>
```

o título que você vê não vem do thead, porque o mesmo é "ocultado" através deste trecho de css:

```
  table thead {
      border: none;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
  }
```

o título no responsivo esta no **data-label**, espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Obrigado por explicar, facilitou bastante meu entendimento sobre, e melhor: deu certo!

Comment: que bom que deu certo :D